# What exactly is Project-118?

Tags: nagi-no-asukara

I know that they are the writers of Nagi no Asukara, just that I wanted to know more about that exactly. A group being named after a "project" sounded curious to me. Can someone tell me more about these authors? (or author)

Comment: It's just a name that a group of writers came up with for themselves, nothing more. They thought it would sound interesting and look where it got them − people are asking questions :)

Comment: https://twitter.com/shiracombo/status/457529612528922624 and https://twitter.com/nanoexpTS2/status/457509532113973248 says that 118 is the sum of the strokes (?) of the staffs in the planning stage, and it is coincidentally the telephone number for Coast Guard. Unfortunately, I don't know who are the staffs in question, so I cannot confirm these 2 tweets.

Comment: @nhahtdh Shinohara Toshiya (director, 44 strokes) + Okada Mari (series composition, 38 strokes) gives us 82 strokes, so if we happen across one or more relevant people that sum to 36 strokes, that might do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

**The meaning of "Project-118" is the sum of the name of the staffs in the planning stage converted to numbers.**

It was explained in the "Nagi no Asukara" Special Staff Talk Show ([凪のあすから　汐鹿生大宴会 ―「凪のあすから」スペシャルスタッフトークショー](https://www.loft-prj.co.jp/schedule/plusone/22229)) on April 19, 2014. Some tweets from it:

> [澤村・スク水・英梨々 @nanoexpTS2](https://twitter.com/nanoexpTS2/status/457509532113973248)
>
> Project118の意味。辻さん **凪のあすからの企画段階のメンバーの名前を数字に変換して足したら118だった**。検索してみたら、海上保安庁の番号だった。[...]
>
> The meaning of Project118. Tsuji (ed. the Animation Producer) said that **if the name of the staffs in the planning stage of Nagi no Asukara is converted to numbers and then summed, the total is 118**. Searching about it, it is the number of Japan Coast Guard. [...]
>
> ---
>
> [しらこ @srcsn](https://twitter.com/srcsn/status/457529612528922624)
>
> **Project-118の118の意味は、製作決定当初のスタッフさんの名前をあてたものを足して118になった**とか。[...] …ちなみに118は海上保安なんたらの番号らしく、海という共通点が偶然にも。
>
> **The meaning of 118 in Project-118 is, when the name of the staffs at the beginning of production decision is "matched"(?), the sum is 118**. [...] ... By the way, looks like 118 is the number of Japan Coast Guard something, having "sea" as a common point is a coincidence.
>
> <sup>(emphasis mine, archived from [togetter (Japanese)](https://togetter.com/li/657114?page=6))</sup>

However, they didn't explain further about the conversion and who the staffs are.

It might be possible as [nhahtdh's comment](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/11669/what-exactly-is-project-118#comment14376_11669) to calculate the kanji strokes of the name (example: 辻充仁 is 5 + 6+4=15), but it's also possible to use [*goroawase*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_wordplay#Goroawase) (example: 辻充仁, *Mitsuhito Tsuji* is 3+2+1+10 + 2+10 = 28 [or any other possible combinations]). But at this point, both are only speculation though.

Comment: That said, if someone is successful in solving this puzzle with sufficient details, feel very free to post it as an answer...